# C# start.process powershell longer runtime than native ps1

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I'm using the following C# code to run a PowerShell script, the script runs within a second when run outside of C# but within the following C# code block it runs in excess of 9 secs. The C# code is compiled and run as a windows service under the same user account (tested by outputting `whoami` in the PowerShell script.)

```
string csv = jobpath + requesttype[2] + ".csv";
string id = "123321";
var scriptfile = @"c:\jobrunner\jobrunner.ps1";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"" + scriptfile + " '" + csv + "' " + " '" + id +     "'";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

The PowerShell script loads functions from a folder like such:

```
$date = get-date
"start $date" >> C:\temp\_log.log
$psdir="c:\Jobrunner\functions"  
# load all 'autoload' scripts
Get-ChildItem "${psdir}\*.ps1" | %{.$_} 
$date = get-date 
"end $date" >> C:\temp\_log.log
```

Can anyone point me in a direction as to why the script is so slow when executed from within C#?

results: (first run native second from c#)

```
start 03/28/2015 16:05:13 - end 03/28/2015 16:05:13 

start 03/28/2015 16:05:32- end 03/28/2015 16:05:41
```

Performance got allot better when using:

```
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
```

i noticed the spawned powershell.exe had *32 first tried C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 but that was actually 32 bit and the powershell.exe in system32 was 64bit?

now the difference is: 0.5 secs vs 1.1 secs

Any further performance boosters are truly appreciated

Comment: Is your C# application compiled for x64 or runs in WoW? Could you add `$env:PROCESS_ARCHITECTURE >> C:\temp\_log.log` to your powershell script and share the results?

Comment: Is there any perf diff if you run powershell.exe with the `-noprofile` parameter?

Comment: AMD64 in both cases.

Comment: how do I add the -noprofile? tried adding in .exe and in addarguments..

Comment: I ran powershell.exe -noprofile c:\jobrunner\jobrunner.ps1 from cmd still fast, how do i add it to my example above?

Comment: Try startInfo.Arguments = @"" + " -noprofile" + scriptfile + " .....